# Is there any way to launch the Global Address List (GAL) Properties Dialog programmatically?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-interop, outlook-addin

Since the advent of Office 2013, I've been increasingly frustrated with the new Outlook contact cards, and the round-about way needed to access the legacy GAL properties dialog as shown below:

[image: Legacy Global Address List Properties]

Essentially I am looking for an API with which I can launch the legacy GAL box programmatically.

A search on this so far has provided no results related to an API, but rather, just the registry key to automatically use the legacy dialog as opposed to contact cards when adding contact entries (TurnOnLegacyGALDialog).

Thanks!

Comment: After digging through some API, I believe this has something to do with the ContactItem object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/contactitem-object-outlook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call AddressEntry.Details() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.details.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes!!!  I don't know why it's so difficult to find this information, maybe it's due to my ignorance on Outlook automation.  Thank you, Dmitry!